# chef common recipe multiple roles

Tags: linux, mongodb, chef, chef-server

i have created a mongodb chef recipe, and i am overriding the default attributes on the recipe from the role.

```
name 'mongo_datanode_jackey'
description 'this module is currently under testing...'

override_attributes(
    susemongodb:  {
        node_type:  'datanode',
        node_nickname: 'jackey',
        port:  '27018',
        is_replicaset_node: true,
        is_cluster_node: true,
        replicaset_name: 'myreplica',
        clusterRole: 'configsvr',
     }

)

run_list(
  "recipe[susemongodb::setupmachine]",
  "recipe[susemongodb::datanode]"
)
```

now, I would like to spin up multiple datanodes within the same VM, so i have created another role similar to above but with different attribute values.

```
name 'mongo_datanode_meerkat'
description 'this module is currently under testing...'

override_attributes(
    susemongodb:  {
        node_type:  'datanode',
        node_nickname: 'meerkat',
        port:  '27019',
        is_replicaset_node: true,
        is_cluster_node: true,
        replicaset_name: 'myreplica',
        clusterRole: 'configsvr',
     }

)

run_list(
  "recipe[susemongodb::setupmachine]",
  "recipe[susemongodb::datanode]"
)
```

If you notice they are using the same recipe, which gets passed the attributes,

I am calling the roles in the client,

```
{
  "name": "mongo1",
  "chef_environment": "development",
  "normal": {
    "tags": [

    ]
  },
  "run_list": [
  "role[mongo_datanode_jackey]",
  "role[mongo_datanode_meerkat]",
  "role[mongo_datanode_zebra]"
]

}
```

however, when chef runs the it runs on the last role on the run_list....any idea why?

```
[2016-02-11T16:51:35+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2016-02-11T16:51:35+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.6.0 ***
[2016-02-11T16:51:35+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 14010
[2016-02-11T16:51:40+00:00] INFO: Run List is [role[mongo_datanode_jackey], role[mongo_datanode_meerkat], role[mongo_datanode_zebra]]
[2016-02-11T16:51:40+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [susemongodb::setupmachine, susemongodb::datanode]
[2016-02-11T16:51:40+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for mongo1
```

I would like each role to be applied on the server and use the common recipe.....?

Answer (score 0):

A node can only have one value value for a given attribute (such as `node["susemongodb"]["node_nickname"]`) and the values are determined during the compile phase (see "Stages" [here](https://docs.chef.io/chef_client.html#the-chef-client-title-run)).

So in your case, and assuming there are no overrides with [higher precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence), the values from the last role in the run-list will be used.

In addition, before starting the converge phase, the initial run-list is expanded to individual recipes. One recipe can only appear once in the expanded run-list, which is why you get:

`INFO: Run List expands to [susemongodb::setupmachine, susemongodb::datanode]`

I don't know how your cookbook is setup but to achieve what you want to could have the `node["susemongodb"]["node_nickname"]` and `node["susemongodb"]["port"]` attributes be arrays and in your recipe iterate over those arrays and execute your resources in the loop.